# MySQL Procedure - Inner for loop condition not producing the correct output

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench, innodb

I am creating a Bar, Beer, Drinker, Likes, Frequents, Transactions schema. Every bar has opening/closing hours for each day of the week.

Specific error: I have an outer loop that goes through each bar, and and inner loop to assign 1-7 opening/closing hour entries for each bar. Despite looping through and attempting to insert 1-7 entries, the INSERT statement only gets triggered once per bar entry in the outer loop.

My opening/closing hours table:

```
Bar Name varchar(45) PK FK 
Bar Phone # INT PK FK
Weekday INT PK
Open Hour TIME
Close Hour TIME
```

Current output consists of a single open/close hour entry per bar:

Opening/Closing Hours table AFTER running the procedure

```
Boone's Brew Inc    2147483647  7   04:55:51    18:39:25
Boondocks Brewing Tap Room & Restaurant 2147483647  4   09:01:01    17:10:09
Boon Island Alehouse    2147483647  1   05:14:24    19:56:57
........ for 957 more bars, all with listed only once in the table with a random weekday
```

Desired output:

```
Boone's Brew Inc    2147483647  7   04:55:51    18:39:25
Boone's Brew Inc    2147483647  6   04:55:51    18:39:25
Boone's Brew Inc    2147483647  5   04:55:51    18:39:25
Boone's Brew Inc    2147483647  4   04:55:51    18:39:25
Boondocks Brewing Tap Room & Restaurant 2147483647  4   09:01:01    17:10:09
Boondocks Brewing Tap Room & Restaurant 2147483647  3   09:01:01    17:10:09
Boondocks Brewing Tap Room & Restaurant 2147483647  2   09:01:01    17:10:09
Boon Island Alehouse    2147483647  1   05:14:24    19:56:57
```

Desired output: 1-7 open/closing hour entries for each bar instead of just strictly 1.

and my procedure is:

```
DROP PROCEDURE fill_hours;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE fill_hours()
BEGIN

    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE j INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE num_of_bars INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE bar_name varchar(45) DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE bar_phone_num INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE weekday INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE open_hour TIME DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE close_hour TIME DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE start_time_factor TIME DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE end_time_factor TIME DEFAULT 0;


    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO num_of_bars FROM Bar;
    WHILE i < num_of_bars DO
    SELECT `Bar Name`, `Bar Phone #` INTO bar_name, bar_phone_num FROM Bar LIMIT i,1;
        weekday: WHILE j < 7 DO
            SET weekday := (1 + FLOOR(RAND() * 7));
            IF EXISTS(SELECT `Bar Name`, `Bar Phone #`, `Weekday` FROM `Opening/Closing Hours` WHERE `Bar Name` = bar_name AND `Bar Phone #` = bar_phone_num AND `Weekday` = weekday) THEN
                SELECT CONCAT("weekday: ", weekday);
                SET j := j + 1;
                ITERATE weekday;
            END IF;
            SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC('13:00:00') + RAND() * (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('13:00:00', '15:00:00'))))) INTO start_time_factor;
            SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC('20:00:00') + RAND() * (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('18:00:00', '19:00:00'))))) INTO end_time_factor;
            SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC(start_time_factor) + RAND() * (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(start_time_factor, '16:00:00'))))) INTO open_hour;
            SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC(end_time_factor) + RAND() * (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time_factor, '23:59:00'))))) INTO close_hour;


            INSERT INTO `Opening/Closing Hours` VALUE(bar_name, bar_phone_num, weekday, open_hour, close_hour);

            SET j := j + 1;
        END WHILE;
    SET i := i + 1;
    SET j := 0;
    END WHILE;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.* You need to supply tables, sample data, actual output and desired output.

Comment: @Richardissimo Sorry about that, I updated the question.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood. For people to be able to help you, they will want to copy your table definition out of the question to create it in their environment. Similar with the sample data (none supplied). You need to give specific desired output for the specific sample data supplied. The harder you make it for people to help, the less likely you will get help. There are some good tips on [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Richardissimo Please see my most recently updated answer which provides specific outputs, both current and desired, as well as a more concise summary of what the problem is.

Comment: Much improved question, well done. *would I need to...post CSV* Not at all. You need a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem. *I posted my table definition...I need to provide the create statements?* Yes. The more you help someone to replicate your problem the more likely they will help you.

Comment: @Richardissimo Thankk you for your help, comparing my original draft and this one, I can see now why it went unanswered for so long haha.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: get rid of the irrelevant fluff, such as the table.  You are complaining that the computations fail to be 'random', correct?  So, is this equivalent to the computations?

```
DROP PROCEDURE fill_hours;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE fill_hours()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE j INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE num_of_bars INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE bar_name varchar(45) DEFAULT "";
    DECLARE bar_phone_num INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE weekday INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE open_hour TIME DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE close_hour TIME DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE start_time_factor TIME DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE end_time_factor TIME DEFAULT 0;

        weekday: WHILE j < 7 DO
            SET weekday := (1 + FLOOR(RAND() * 7));
            SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC('13:00:00') + RAND() * (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('13:00:00', '15:00:00'))))) INTO start_time_factor;
            SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC('20:00:00') + RAND() * (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('18:00:00', '19:00:00'))))) INTO end_time_factor;
            SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC(start_time_factor) + RAND() * (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(start_time_factor, '16:00:00'))))) INTO open_hour;
            SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(FLOOR(TIME_TO_SEC(end_time_factor) + RAND() * (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end_time_factor, '23:59:00'))))) INTO close_hour;
            -- For debugging:
            SELECT weekday, open_hour, close_hour;
            SET j := j + 1;
        END WHILE;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

But that seems to work OK...

```
mysql> call fill_hours();
+---------+-----------+------------+
| weekday | open_hour | close_hour |
+---------+-----------+------------+
|       3 | 11:19:41  | 17:07:07   |
+---------+-----------+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

+---------+-----------+------------+
| weekday | open_hour | close_hour |
+---------+-----------+------------+
|       6 | 07:43:48  | 17:06:57   |
+---------+-----------+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

+---------+-----------+------------+
| weekday | open_hour | close_hour |
+---------+-----------+------------+
|       5 | 09:55:03  | 15:56:42   |
+---------+-----------+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

+---------+-----------+------------+
| weekday | open_hour | close_hour |
+---------+-----------+------------+
|       2 | 10:11:17  | 19:42:50   |
+---------+-----------+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

+---------+-----------+------------+
| weekday | open_hour | close_hour |
+---------+-----------+------------+
|       6 | 09:58:52  | 18:58:02   |
+---------+-----------+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

+---------+-----------+------------+
| weekday | open_hour | close_hour |
+---------+-----------+------------+
|       4 | 11:26:18  | 18:02:06   |
+---------+-----------+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

+---------+-----------+------------+
| weekday | open_hour | close_hour |
+---------+-----------+------------+
|       3 | 11:35:00  | 17:18:14   |
+---------+-----------+------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

For now, I will respond with "Works For Me".

If you think the `INSERT` might be the problem, then do a similar paring down to isolate (as much as practical) the `INSERT`.  Maybe then you (or we) can see what is wrong.